# Show list of pages that are opened at the time being

Tags: asp.net

I have a task to list all pages which are opened at that moment and show how many people are on that page.

*I am looking for a way to make that happen without keeping any db records or saving information on a text file or smth like that.* (Not seccessarily, then. Of course I am going to save that info to a dB, I just wanted to the logic of catching opened page addresses.)

I can of course keep track of every page which are opened till that time, but I want the page address appear on the page when someone opens that address and disappear when user is no longer browsing that address.

Can you give me some ideas how to make that happen using ASP.NET?

Note: I am using web forms with asp.net 4.5

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a publically visible website?

Comment: To know what pages are open you'll be looking at some sort of ajax pinging(?), but you wont be able to achieve much without writing to a db or a file somewhere, surely?

Comment: (Updated the question) Yes, it is a public site and I want that to show current status of pages visited by guests in the admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I just wanted to the logic of catching opened page addresses"

Use javascript in a timed loop (onload and then every 30 seconds perhaps) on every page, to asynchronously post to a page on your server. It should send information identifying the page. This will give you a good idea of how many people currently are on this page.

Store this information in a db in your code-behind, and use this information to report as you wish.

Of course if a user leaves their browser open on one of these pages or opens another tab it will still be reporting as 'open'.

To get the current url in javascript you can use:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Is that how google anaytics and other visitor counter services work? Send an ajax request every 5-10 seconds to a server and track may be user IPs to resolve unique visitors or may be create a GUID on the client side for every onload and send a request with page url and that guid, IP, etc.? Is that how it works really, or that's how you would do it :)

Comment: @ilter GA does use asynchronous javascript in a similar way, but only in a single hit on document load. They don't do the pinging thing. This is the only way I can think of to ascertain whether a page is still open in someone's browser without the user interacting with the page. GA, I think, bases current user info only on page loads, and I'd imagine if a user fails to visit any more pages after x minutes it assumes they have gone.

Comment: @ilter to be precise GA actually calls javascript from their servers and with this they ascertain the page details. The modern GA code does this asynch

Comment: Yeah, you're right on this. I just opened my Google Analytics account and realized that after opening a site which is registered in GA, I see myself in real-time section. After some time, visitor count resets because of no page activity. In my scenario I need to repeate that step periodically to make sure if the user is still connected. Thanks for the tip. You definitely pointed me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

In [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) you can see what pages are being used in near-real time.

Why not use that to solve this issue - it's easy to setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joe. I think that's a good idea, but as I mentioned on the question, I need to show that info on the panel. And using google analytics for that scenario involves using anaytics API and it's a long proccess to search and learn it's docs for now. Best to use own method for this task.